# I am not able to scheduling the below code

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, csv, scheduled-job, emailfileattachment

When I am trying to schedule this below code:

```
global class exportReport3 implements System.Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/00O90000008euMXAUH?csv=1');
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attachment.setFileName('report.csv');
        attachment.setBody(Blob.valueof(report.getContent().toString()));
        attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );
        message.setSubject('Report');
        message.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.');
        message.setToAddresses( new String[] { 'hari.a@gmail.com' } );
        message.setCcAddresses(new String[] { 'hari.cc@gmail.com'});
        Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } );

    }
}
```

Then I got the below Error:

```
Scheduler: failed to execute scheduled job: jobId: 7079E000024l9gG, class: common.apex.async.AsyncApexJobObject, reason: Callout from scheduled Apex not supported.
```

Could you please anyone Help me.

Comment: Anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Implement **Database.AllowsCallouts** 
That is , your code will be

```
global class exportReport3 implements Schedulable, Database.AllowsCallouts { 
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) { 
        ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/00O90000008euMXAUH?csv=1'); 
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment(); 
        attachment.setFileName('report.csv'); 
        attachment.setBody(Blob.valueof(report.getContent().toString())); 
        attachment.setContentType('text/csv'); 
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
        message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } ); 
        message.setSubject('Report'); 
        message.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.'); 
        message.setToAddresses( new String[] { 'hari.a@gmail.com' } ); 
        message.setCcAddresses(new String[] { 'hari.cc@gmail.com'}); 
        Messaging.[( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } );

    }
}
```

If you want to do it in the schedule class you will need to do it in an `@future` method.

Comment: when I am using @future method ,this one not support to SchedulableContext .like this error:  Future methods do not support parameter type of System.SchedulableContext

Comment: when i am using Database.AllowsCallouts again i got same error:Scheduler: failed to execute scheduled job: jobId: 7073N0000009h7P, class: common.apex.async.AsyncApexJobObject, reason: Callout from scheduled Apex not supported.